# Filtering with groupby using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a below sample dataframe. I want to filter operation on group of users based on there count. Below operation works fine if I have say 50k users and 45M rows. However my data set is much bigger and every time I try to run this operation it hungs up. Is there more efficient way to perform same task for larger dataset ?

```
df.groupby('Col1').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
```

df

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
1     a.   b.    c
1     a.   c     b
2     c.   d.    a
3     d.   e.    a
4     e.   d.    c
2.    c.   d.    c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dataframe.Groupby` with `transform` and create a boolean series to do boolean indexing which could be faster.   Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = pd.concat([df]*10_000)

%timeit df.groupby('Col1').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
# 7.81 ms ± 59.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df[df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].transform('size') > 1]
# 3.25 ms ± 124 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to consider using [polars](/questions/tagged/polars) ? Here is some timings on my machine :

```
# OP's approach
pd_df.groupby("Col1").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
# 21.23837924003601 seconds

# Scott Boston's approach
pd_df[pd_df.groupby("Col1")["Col1"].transform("size") > 2]
# 2.057915449142456 seconds

# polars' approach
pl_df.filter(pl.col("Col1").count().over("Col1") > 2)
# 1.4760551452636719 seconds
```

Used inputs :

```
import numpy as np
#pip install polars
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

G = 50_000
R = 45_000_000

pl_df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Col1": np.random.randint(1, G+1, size=R),
    "Col2": np.random.choice(list("abcde"), size=R),
    "Col3": np.random.choice(list("fghij"), size=R),
    "Col4": np.random.choice(list("kmlno"), size=R)
})

pd_df = pl_df.to_pandas()
```